# C++ casting in new operator

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm c++ newbie and i'm a little bit confused with this code:

```
var *pointer=new(sharemem) var();
```

I've honestly tried to found similar question, but it was unsuccessful. I think because of my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a cast, it is called "placement new" and you can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new

It is essentially constructing a new `var` in pre-allocated memory pointed to by `sharemem`.